# xamarin Android Deployment on Android Mobile Device Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Sir, 
  Previously when ever I have deployed my android application using xamarin on visual studio 2017 the application would be deployed perfectly. But after watching a video for google Map tutorial as : [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Q0olRPsus`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Q0olRPsus), I am unable to deploy application on android device and on emulator as well.

Now I am getting the following error on deployment : `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]`.

This is my error log File : [`https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRZzMtLV9nc3M5RlU`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRZzMtLV9nc3M5RlU)

**Manifest Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="VaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <permission android:name="VaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="VaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-features android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <application android:label="VaishnoDeviTourismApp" android:icon="@drawable/logo">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBRVXFw2TXfTLDr1Dzu8-HDiv-FQJdEZ3E" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please show your manifest? This error means you've errors in your manifest.

Comment: Sir I have edited above question and added my manifest file code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing your manifest, we found that the error occurred with your permission `<permission android:name="VaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />`.

The `VaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp...` should be your package name, the first letter is upper case in your scenario, we may need to change it to lowercase. Like this `vaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp...`. Or you may try to change it like this `<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature">`

I didn't find any document point out this rule, actually, on the contrary, the the document says:

> The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.

So, I can only consider it as a bug for now, and I found this [report in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19978).

Comment: Sir is it mandatory to keep first word lowercase in `Package name`  ? And can we change it manually to lowercase ? Because `VaishnoDeviTourismApp.VaishnoDeviTourismApp` is a package name of my application and was created by default while creating project.

Comment: @SumeetKumar, yeah, I've the same doubt, as I said, there is no mandatory to keep first word lowercase, this is why I  said it's a potential bug. And you may try to use `<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature">`, in native java android, the `${applicationId}` should automatically point to your package id.